# C# Accurately Replace String/SubString

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I have large entries (in array) of Pinyin tone notation, some string are combined, for example `Diànnǎo` = `Diàn` + `nǎo`

Now problem is I want replace a string that contain 2 or more, for example:

```
string[] Py = { "xi", "xia", "xian" };
string[] Km = { "shi", "shie, "shien" };
string[] Input = "xiaguo";
for (int i = 0; i < Py.Length; i++)
    if (Input.Contains(Py[i]))
        Input = Input.Replace(Py[i], Km[i]);
```

Code above have a problem due to loop index, `xiaguo` contains `xi` become true `(shiaguo)` not `(shieguo)` since `xi` get first before `xia`

How do I achieve this? and make sure get `xia` instead of `xi`

Full code I posted on GitHub: https://github.com/Anime4000/py2km/blob/beta/py2km.api/Converter.cs#L15

Comment: Sort your arrays based on character length in descending order and then apply your logic. Also use a `Dictionary<string,string>` instead of two arrays based on same index.

Comment: Side note: You don't need to check `Contains` before calling replace, if it doesn't contain the given string, result string is unchanged.

Comment: Habib, I converted array into Dictionary, now I lost... [See code](https://github.com/Anime4000/py2km/blob/beta/py2km.api/Converter.cs#L15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming longer tokens take precedence over shorter tokens, the 2 arrays can be converted to a dictionary and then sorted by the length of the key:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  {"xi","shi"},
  {"xia","shie"},   
  {"xian","shien"},
}.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Length)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Key)
  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

string input = "xiaguo";

foreach(var d in dic)
  input = input.Replace(d.Key, d.Value);

Console.WriteLine(input);
```

The above example with sort the dictionary:

- by the length of the key
- then by the alpha sort of the key
- finally, the LINQ query is converted back to a dictionary.

From there, just iterate over the dictionary and replace all the tokens; there's no need to check to see if the key/token exists.

Comment: Your method works fine, I [modified _(link to github)_](https://github.com/Anime4000/py2km/blob/beta-2/py2km.api/Converter.cs#L1147) to using `TryGetValue` method to avoid 2nd replace and exact. But word not in dict will skipped, how to display no-related?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a regular expresion for this.
I modified your code so the regex wil only match xi and not xia.
the regex "xi\b" matches xi and the \b means word boundary so it only matches that exact word.

```
string[] Py = { "xi", "xia", "xian" };
string[] Km = { "shi", "shie, "shien" };
string[] Input = "xiaguo";
string pattern = "xi\b"
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

for (int i = 0; i < Py.Length; i++)
{
     MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(Py[i]);
     if (matches.Count > 0)
     {
        Input = Input.Replace(Py[i], Km[i]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tone/language specifics could not have an easy structure, so you may assume some pattern and then find out later that it's not right for some 'word'.
Anyway, to handle the informed scenario, you must order the target tone by descending length, and then perform only a single replacement for each 'word' (this will avoid replacing **xi**, **xia** when processing **xian**.

The steps would be:

1. for each replacement ordered by length descending
2. try to find tone
3. if found: replace and mark as done (jump to next 'word')

The idea here is the same as when replacing a two numbers in a list, say 2 to 1 and 3 to 2, for example. The order really matter, if you replace 3 by 2 then you will be replacing both 3 and 2 to 1 after all.